# Animate jquery filter with toggle duration

Tags: jquery

I'm building a filter in Bootstrap and trying to get the filtered out divs to fade out using toggle()

```
     $("#searchInput").on("keyup", function() {
       var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
       $("#group div.container-fluid").filter(function() {
         $(this).toggle( $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1 ), 1000
       });
     });
```

I keep getting this error:
k.easing[this.easing] is not a function

jquery UI effects core is included on my page already.

Here is a codepen:
https://codepen.io/pataig/pen/GbVLKJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there will be syntax error first as you haven't closed the toggle method.

```
$("#searchInput").on("keyup", function() {
   var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
   $("#consultants div.container-fluid").hide().filter(function() {
     return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1;
   }).fadeIn("slow");
 });
```

The syntax of the fadeout method if you want to apply easing

```
$(selector).fadeOut(speed,easing,callback)
```

Comment: Your snippet does have the fade effect I'm trying to achieve, but it breaks the search filter... I've updated the question with a codepen

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQueryUI in-order to get easing effects.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-KM512VNnjElC30ehFwehXjx1YCHPiQkOPmqnrWtpccM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You're not wrong, but I've already got jQuery UI included and it still returns the error.